# Camel SFTP fetch on schedule and on demand

Tags: apache-camel, sftp

I can see similar problems in different variations but haven't managed to find a definite answer.

Here is the usecase:

- SFTP server that I want to poll from every hour
- on top of that, I want to expose a REST endpoint that the user can hit do force an ad-hoc retrieval from that same SFTP. I'm happy with the schedule on the polling to remain as-is, i.e. if I polled, 20 mins later the user forces refresh, the next poll can be 40 mins later.

Both these should be idempotent in that a file that was downloaded using the polling mechanism should not be downloaded again in ad-hoc pull and vice-versa. Both ways of accessing should download ALL the files available that were not yet downloaded (there will likely be more than one new file - I saw a similar question here for on-demand fetch but it was for a single file).

I would like to avoid hammering the SFTP via pollEnrich - my understanding is that each pollEnrich would request a fresh list of files from SFTP, so doing pollEnrich in a loop until all files are retrieved would be calling the SFTP multiple times.

I was thinking of creating a route that will start/stop a separate route for the ad-hoc fetch, but I'm not sure that this would allow for the idempotent behaviour between routes to be maintained.

So, smart Camel brains out there, what is the most elegant way of fulfilling such requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Not a smart camel brain, but I would give a try as per my understanding.

Hope, you already went through:

http://camel.apache.org/file2.html

http://camel.apache.org/ftp2.html

I would have created a filter, separate routes for consumer and producer.

And for file options, I would have used: idempotent, delay, initialDelay, useFixedDelay=true, maxMessagesPerPoll=1, eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll as true, readLock=idempotent, idempotent=true, idempotentKey=${file:onlyname}, idempotentRepository, recursive=false
- For consuming.
No files will be read again! You can use a diversity of options as documented and try which suits you the best, like delay option. If yo

"I would like to avoid hammering the SFTP via pollEnrich - my understanding is that each pollEnrich would request a fresh list of files from SFTP, so doing pollEnrich in a loop until all files are retrieved would be calling the SFTP multiple times." - > Unless you use the option disconnect=true, the connection will not be terminated and you can either consume or produce files continously, check ftp options for disconnect and disconnectOnBatchComplete.

Hope this helps!